# How to set Layoutparams of child view without affecting parent view?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, resize

I have a custom row view for a list. Say there are 2 components a parent and a child....i want to maintain the height of the parent to be constant when i change the height of the child...

I have set the parent height constant and the height of the child is varied dynamically.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and during runtime,

```
child.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, x);
```

where x is a varying height variable.
Still the height of the parent is getting affected. any solutions?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail:
1) Are there any other children (siblings)?
2) Is the linearlayout parent the parent of the layout, or is it embedded within another layout (and if so, what's the layout_height setting for that parent)?
3) Do you ever set x larger than 150dp (your parent height)?

Comment: 1) hey, there are other siblings, but nothing depends on each other
2)Linearlayout is the root layout, it doesn have any parent
3)No i dont set x>150 ever

Answer (score 0):

If the LinearLayout is the root view, when you are inflating it the params android:layout_width and android:layout_height are changed by android, if it is a row inside a list, then they will have the width match_parent and the height wrap_content. If you want to keep a constant height for the row you will have to set the layout params programatically after you inflate the view.